# Need help with DIsk Space

Tags: dual-boot, disk, disk-usage

I Dual booted Ubuntu (Alongside windows 7) with a thumb drive, so I cant take off Ubuntu, but when I installed it I choose the Default Disk Space for windows and Ubuntu, but I need more for Ubuntu, without reinstalling (or UN-installing, or programming) Is there any way i can add more??? This is the Video I based installing Ubuntu on -> "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uVcsFhv2Vo"

Answer (score 0):

You can resize partitions using gparted.

1. Open a terminal (CTRL + ALT + T)
2. Install gparted using

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gparted
   ```
3. Launch it via dash or by running

   ```
   sudo gparted
   ```
4. Select the partition you want to resize and click the 'Resize' button.
5. When you're done making changes, hit 'Apply'.

Comment: How do i resize the partition? I opened it, took some off windows 7, and it created a new unmounted partition, then i couldn't figure out what to do next. Do you have a skype or point me towards a youtube video?

Comment: It would help me a lot if you could upload a screenshot of gparted to imgur and then post the link as a comment. So you shrunk the Windows 7 partition and it created some free space behind it. Now, to enlarge the Ubuntu partition, move it as far to the left as possible (also using 'Resize/Move', just grab the partition and move it to the left.) and enlarge it to the greatest possible size.